# HTML5 video on iPad - ONLY display in full screen

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, video

I'm building a HTML5 web app that will only be viewed on iPad. I have a link: 'Tap here to view video', where once that link is tapped, the corresponding video will automatically go into iOS's full screen view. Once the video is closed, it will obviously close and you will no longer see anything of that video.

Is this even possible?

Currently, I'm initially hiding my video and then when I'm tapping on my link, the video appears, but it isn't full screen mode. Then (obviously) it just stays there on the screen.

HTML:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0);" class = "rationale-video-icon video1"></a>

<video class="video_player" id="player" width="100%" controls autoplay>
    <source src="videos/1.11-1.39 Diagnosis Investigations and StagingConverted.mp4"/>
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.  Use a better browser!
</video>
```

JS:

```
$('.video1').click(function(){
       $('#player').show().get( 0 ).play();
       var elem = document.getElementById("player");
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
       elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#player {
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Any help appreciated! Cheers.